# xcode 8 error denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace)

Tags: xcode, xcode8, xcode10

Trying to run a build on simulator and I get this error:

> The request to open "com.companyname.appname" failed.
>
> The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for
> reason: Security ("Entitlement
> "com.apple.frontboard.debugapplications" required to launch
> applications for debugging").

This was not there when using the GM of `Xcode 8`, but started soon as I downloaded it again form the mac app store.
Google is no help neither is the Apple developers forum.

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 338, accepted):

Quitting the simulator and relaunching fixed this for me.

Comment: Also, if quitting the simulator doesn't solve the problem , then you should make sure that in Edit Scheme all the fields are unchecked.

Comment: This was the solution for me. I think the cause of the issue was that I left the simulator open while installing an Xcode point update.

Comment: YES, It happened after xCode upgrade complete.

Comment: This. It happens if you update XCode while the simulator is opened. You have to restart the simulator too for it to work again.

Comment: Oh, great, another Xcode "fix" that does not pause me in my workflow at all. At least it's a no-brainer.

Comment: I need to reset the data on simulator to fix this, but it keeps coming back. Any idea?

Comment: I faced the same issue today, I found a solution just installing another iOS simulator version. I was using 10.3, now and using 10.2 and working perfectly so far.

Answer (score 102):

[image: Empty setting causing error]

In case anyone is wondering what is meant by "empty settings" that should be unchecked as mentioned in the answer of maricle and in the comment of  Vinayak GH
At least that is what caused the problem for me.

Comment: I didn't know I upvoted this in 2016 and couldn't let me upvote again! lol This is still the case in Xcode 10.2.1.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me on macOS 10.15.4, Xcode 11.4

Answer (score 16):

Make Sure that you have not Checked Any "empty settings" in Product > Scheme > Edit scheme > Run > Environment variables. this cause the above issue.

Comment: +1 This is the problem I had. I removed an Environment variable and looks like I did not remove it properly.

Comment: Tried everything and sure enough I had an empty setting! Also +1

Answer (score 13):

check your scheme settings and make sure all empty settings are unchecked.

Answer (score 13):

The only thing that worked for me was:

Simulator > Reset Content And Setting

Then clean and run your project

Answer (score 3):

I have suffered from this problem for a couple days. Basically I have tried every way which can be found on the internet but none of those was helpful indeed. I even reinstalled Xcode two times (Xcode 8.3.2 8E2002, simulator iOS 10.3 14E269). And of course, there was nothing wrong with my project, scheme and empty settings.. everything seems normal. Finally I found that the best way to solve this is before you deploy your app to the simulator, you should clean your project (shift + cmd + K) and then you run again (cmd + R). This will solve your problem.

Comment: Update: I found out that the recent iOS 10.3 simulator causes this problem. When I download and use iOS 10.1 simulator to run my source code, the problem never appear again.

Answer (score 3):

Build Setting > Combined > Linking > Mach - o - type change to executable

This worked for me because I had changed that to static before.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem seems to be related to my being a bit too hasty to remove some red-hilighted Pod frameworks. I thought they were missing, but the entitlement error started immediately after I removed them. The error persisted until I ran `pod install` to reinstate the deleted Pod frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall (Delete) App from Simulator and run it again. works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the other suggestions in here, and for me, it would fix if I restart Xcode and simulator, then it would work once. After that, the issue would start happening again until I did another restart.

What fixed it for me was to delete the scheme and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I use "/" character in target name. Fixed after deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 10: Erase All content on simulator > Quit Xcode > Reopen XCode & Rebuild worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your project's Build System to New Build System...
Xcode -> File -> Workspace Setting -> Build System : New Build System.[image]