# Xcode : Request to open App failed

Tags: ios, xcode

Sometime before everything works fine & running project but right now I am getting issue that `request to open App failed`.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea to fix this and why does this issue occurs?

Comment: I misread the image message. I have removed the duplicate flag, but check if this thread can help with any of the issue even tho it is different error log it might be related solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495620/xcode-8-error-denied-by-service-delegate-sbmainworkspace

Comment: Is it on a device or the simulator?

Comment: hey i got that quit simulator works for me but still i didn't understand clearly why does this issue occurs evrytime?

Comment: @Siriss its occurs on the simulator.

Comment: That moment when you censor out the app name but forget to censor out the other app name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Cause**

Might be you have run different the project sometime before on assume iphone 6s Plus & without closing it or you left it is in the background & now if you are trying to run another project on iphone 5s it's a cause i believe you are facing this issue.

**Fix**

Just quit simulator & run your project again resolved your issue.

**More solutions,**

[xcode 8 error denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495620/xcode-8-error-denied-by-service-delegate-sbmainworkspace)

Comment: exactly sir i did same thing on my xcode. You mean am i need to close prev. running project before running another project right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact reason why this problem occurs. I've analyzed occurance of this problem can be anyone of following:

- Change in bundle identifier for existing project (running in device or simulator)

- Last running build was not stopped properly or last running build is busy in background.

- Your system/Xcode performing too slower (may be due to Project size or system configuration) and it takes too much time to run your project/build

Here are few steps to solve this (Any one or all of these works)

- Clean your XCode

- Clean up project cache and other backup files from Library (It's not user library, press alter option/button keyboard and Click on 'Go' menu of finder) >> Developer >> "Project" directory

- Remove existing build from Device/simulator

- Restart your simulator or device.

- Restart system (Shutdown and again start after few seconds)

This will solve your problem.

Comment: hello sir i don't have changed the bundle identifier but its look like might be  your second points matched my case.

Comment: Please don't call sir, we are all here friend, and together here to help each other. You may be facing this problem because any one of reasons that i've mentioned here as there is no exact reason for occurance of this issue for latest Xcode. Follow resolution steps i mentioned here, you will solution from any one step of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use

> xcrun simctl list

to get the list of all simulators

And then

> xcrun simctl erase all

to reset all the simulators i.e to remove all the data.

First quit the simulator then use this command otherwise you will get an error like this "An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=163. Unable to boot device in current state: Booted"

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen a few times. I ran `xcrun simctl erase all` and reset all my simulators and it fixed it. I think sometimes, if you are switching devices in the simulator, it gets stuck in certain states. Make sure the simulator is quit before running the command in Terminal.

Comment: `xcrun simctl erase all` is this command i need to run from terminal? is there need to set path on terminal before fire this command?

Comment: Yes that is the command. You don't need to specify a path to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this below simple step

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme >Run >Info > Build Configuration > debug mode

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and just fixed it.
The solution was to remove an empty environment variable in my schema.
Below is a screenshot of the diff, with the removed area highlighted.

Once the highlighted section below was removed from the .xcscheme file, I could resume running the App from XCode normally.

[image: diff showing region to remove]