# How to fix installation of flutter application in iOS devices?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm new in flutter and iOS also, I was developing my first project in flutter using Windows then done but now I want to develop an iOS app. So, I copied my project from Windows and paste into Mac. I installed all thing which is related to flutter. Now, When i am trying to install an app on simulator then

> Xcode showing error : 
>   The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified.

I searched a lot on same error but i did not find the solution of this.I searched on github and stackoverflow also but their answer did not work.

Flutter doctor :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

My App is installing but when it appears then suddenly crash and xcode showing error message box.How to fix it ?
If someone has query or any question then ask me please.Thank you.

Comment: Have you gone through with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495620/xcode-8-error-denied-by-service-delegate-sbmainworkspace)?

Comment: try quitting simulator and rerun the app.

Comment: @TheTiger already tried...i'm using xcode 10.2..No argument at there and no any blank variable at there.

Comment: tried many times...i also restarted my Mac but did not work @NikhilGangurde

Comment: I was saying to reset the simulator ... there were multiple solutions in that answer... have tried all?

Comment: which file did you open in the XCode project folder.

Comment: I did not find this one Simulator > Reset Content And Setting

where is Reset Content And Setting Option @TheTiger

Comment: Runner.xcworkspace @NikhilGangurde

Comment: @KiritoKun007 Its there `Simulator -> Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings`.

Comment: @TheTiger that problem solved but now it is saying 
Library not found for -IFirebaseAuth.
I unchecked firebase_auth in Target Membership since morning... is it problem ?

Comment: @KiritoKun007 Many reasons for this error. library is not setup properly. Accidentally you have changed its path. You have opened `xcodeproj` file instead of `xcworkspace`. `pod` configuration error if so then install pod again. If you manually setup this library probably you missed something ... check build settings point in tutorial, may be you missed `other linker flags`, `framework search path`.  etc. etc....

Comment: No, i opened Runner.xcworkspace.
If library is not setup properly then how to reset,
I reinstall pod now but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

You may want to check your scheme. The executable should be asked on launch.

**Edit Scheme -> Info -> Executable -> Ask on launch**

[image]

reference apple forum answer: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/258839

Comment: tried but it did not work. but now my error is different it's showing Library not found for -IFirebaseAuth.
What to do ?

Comment: check pods first if they are ok check path of IFirebaseAuth in "linker search paths" of the project (for both Debug and Release builds).

Comment: i opened Pods, now i can see all targets. There is firebase_auth and FirebaseAuth.I clicked on both and in Build setting i am searching linker search paths then there is showing nothing. linker search paths is in build setting na ?

Comment: why do you have two

Comment: try removing one if you use both xcode will get confuse and will give you error

Comment: i want to show u in picture can you share your contact bcz here is no option ?

Comment: yes there is edit your question and paste image in there