# Flutter app fails to build on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Currently, I am in quite the pickle with getting my flutter app running on Xcode's ios simulator.  Prior to these issues it has worked, but now I get this build error after calling flutter run:

```
Exception: Unable to launch alfarogavin2705-icloud.com.kiwis on 8A6F9997-A0BA-441A-A48E-40503A7E3DA4:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
alfarogavin2705-icloud.com.kiwis: -1

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "alfarogavin2705-icloud.com.kiwis" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Busy ("Application failed preflight
checks").
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=6):
        The operation couldn’t be completed. Application failed preflight checks
        Application failed preflight checks
  Command: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch 8A6F9997-A0BA-441A-A48E-40503A7E3DA4 alfarogavin2705-icloud.com.kiwis
  --enable-dart-profiling --enable-checked-mode --verify-entry-points --observatory-port=0
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

I honestly don't know what is causing this error.

Comment: have you tried to restart the simulator? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495620/xcode-8-error-denied-by-service-delegate-sbmainworkspace

Comment: You might want to try running the command from your error log directly in Terminal (possibly with a verbose flag) and then see if you can get a better understanding of what's going wrong.

Comment: I get this error when I add the 'Scan' library. When I remove the library, i don't get the error anymore. Did you find any possible solution for this kind of error yet?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I think it is because of some caching issues. Close and open another simulator device works for me.